# How to replace phpunit assertion message?

Tags: phpunit, output, assertions

How do I replace an assertion error message? If I call `$this->assertTrue(false, 'message')`, it will display both the string "message" and also another message stating that false is not true. How do I get it to *only* output the message that I chose? Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm wondering the reason you need this for. Are you maybe using the same assertion type for all the checks? `Like assertTrue($a == $b)`.

Comment: Because so far, the only way I can find to define a custom assertion with a custom message, is to write a class that extends PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint - which is annoying, when I can just use one of the existing constraints by preprocessing the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

code-crutch which comes to my mind when I faced the same problem:

```
public function assertTrue($condition, $message = '')
{
    if (!$condition) $this->fail($message);
}
```

Comment: It's wrong to do that because if the method does not fail, it does not count as an assertion, and you may have some risky test, and a wrong total of assertions at the end.

Answer (score 0):

With PHPUnit 6 you must have got one assertion at least, so i suggest a little edited @avolkov answer:

```
public function assertTrue($condition, $message = '')
{

    if (!$condition){
      $this->fail($message); //This will cause test fail with your message
    }
    else{
      $this->anything(); //This will eliminate error which says that your test doesn't have assertion
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

It's not possible.

Why would you want to do so? Never encountered a case in which the default message is not helpful in any way. The custom message should add information, not replace the default one.

Comment: Because if I want to define a custom assertion, I can't wrap an existing one (e.g. assertThat) because it will product it's own message. since everything comes down to an assertTrue in the end, you get messages like "Failed asserting that X has property Y. Failed asserting that false is true", which is annoying and not helpful.

Comment: This depends on each one's opinion but let me show a real example: $this->assertNull($this->router->match($url), "URL '{$url}' matched and should have not"); In this example, I will see the normal error, showing me WHAT was really returned, which is helpful, and my custom error message that helps understanding WHY it's not ok. EDIT: this goes inside a custom assertion called assertUrlDoesNotMatch($url)

Comment: Wouldn't the assertion response message for that just be "Object does not match expected NULL"? that doesn't seem helpful to include - your example appears to be a good case for when you would WANT to ignore the default message.